# Is it possible to display props on a parent component?

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to **DISPLAY** props on parent component in React?
Is this similar to passing props from child component to parent component?

Comment: a callback is feasible?

Comment: Do you wan to access to data stored in the parent component? What exactly do you want to do? Can you describe it a little bit ?

Comment: Props are passes to child components, not from child components.  Why do you think you need this?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do you mean the opposite? That is, from parent to child ?

Comment: no I not mean to pass props from child to parent component, but to display props on parent parent component.

Comment: @Dev_jay: What "props" are you referring to?  Parent components pass props to child components.  Which means the parent component already has that data.  So, yes, you can display data in React.  It's really not clear what you're trying to do or what isn't working.  Can you update the question to include an example of what you've attempted and how it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

React and many other modern frameworks (like Vue) have what they call a top-down data flow:

> This is commonly called a “top-down” or “unidirectional” data flow.
> Any state is always owned by some specific component, and any data or
> UI derived from that state can only affect components “below” them in
> the tree.
>
> If you imagine a component tree as a waterfall of props, each
> component’s state is like an additional water source that joins it at
> an arbitrary point but also flows down.

What you can do instead is supply the child component with an event listener and update the parent component's state accordingly.

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [parentState, setParentState] = useState(null)

  return (
    <ChildComponent
      onTextChange={(newState) => setParentState(newState)}
      value={parentState}
    />
  )
}

const ChildComponent = ({ onTextChange, value }) => {
  return <input type="text" value={value} onChange={onTextChange} />
}
```

Comment: Hi Michiel, You can't set parent state technically from child component. However you can pass the data to parents by the same way you are doing and call the setState in the parent container.

Comment: The parent is setting it's own state :-)

Comment: I thought I'm commenting in the original post :)